# "The trial period for this product has expired." 

Tags: 2007

i am getting error when i try to create a site .
"The trial period for this product has expired."

Error logs is below :

The trial period for this product has expired.
01/26/2011 16:53:05.69  w3wp.exe (0x17EC)                           0x013C  CMS                             Publishing Provisioning         75ot    Unexpected  Publishing Feature activation failed. Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The trial period for this product has expired.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CmsSecurityUtilities.EnsureEvaluationNotExpired()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingFeatureHandler.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties receiverProperties).
01/26/2011 16:53:05.69  w3wp.exe (0x17EC)                           0x013C  Windows SharePoint Services     Feature Infrastructure          88jm    High        Feature receiver assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c', class 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingFeatureHandler', method 'FeatureActivated' for feature '22a9ef51-737b-4ff2-9346-694633fe4416' threw an exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The trial period for this product has expired.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CmsSecurityUtilities.EnsureEvaluationNotExpired()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingFeatureHandler.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties receiverProperties)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.DoActivationCallout(Boolean fActivate, Boolean fForce)
01/26/2011 16:53:05.69  w3wp.exe (0x17EC)                           0x013C  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         72by    High        Feature Activation: Threw an exception, attempting to roll back.  Feature 'Publishing' (ID: '22a9ef51-737b-4ff2-9346-694633fe4416').  Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The trial period for this product has expired.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CmsSecurityUtilities.EnsureEvaluationNotExpired()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingFeatureHandler.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties receiverProperties)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.DoActivationCallout(Boolean fActivate, Boolean fForce)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, Boolean fForce)
01/26/2011 16:53:05.69  w3wp.exe (0x17EC)                           0x013C  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8l36    High        Failed to activate site-scoped features for template 'CMSPUBLISHING#0' in site 'http://pmmb2cdev02:801/EN/sdfsdfsd'.
01/26/2011 16:53:05.69  w3wp.exe (0x17EC)                           0x013C  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         72h9    High        Failed to apply template "CMSPUBLISHING#0" to web at URL "http://dev02:801/EN/sdfsdfsd".
01/26/2011 16:53:05.69  w3wp.exe (0x17EC)                           0x013C  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         72k2    High        Failed to apply template "CMSPUBLISHING#0" to web at URL "http://dev02:801/EN/sdfsdfsd", error The trial period for this product has expired. 0x8107058a

Comment: http://dhondiyals.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/the-trial-period-for-this-product-has-expired-sharepoint-resolved/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install the hotfix for SP2?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971620

Comment: after a day . got it :)